# Issue with Creating Conda Environment

Tags: python, git, github, conda, environment

I’m trying to run the code below in the command line from Anaconda Prompt to create a virtual Python environment from a YML file. The virtual environment is named `environment.yml`.

However, when I run the code below, I get this message: `CondaValueError: prefix already exists : C:\Users\super\miniconda3\envs\botty`. The environment also doesn’t get created. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

**Code**

```
git clone https://github.com/bottytools/botty.git
cd botty
conda env create -f environment.yml
conda activate botty
python src/main.py
```

**environment.yml**

```
name: botty
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - pywin32
  - pip
  - leptonica
  - tesseract=5.1.0
  - pkg-config
  - rapidfuzz
  - pip:
    - pyinstaller
    - opencv-python==4.5.5.64
    - transitions
    - mss
    - numpy
    - mouse
    - keyboard
    - beautifultable
    - pytweening
    - requests
    - coverage
    - pytest
    - pytest-env
    - pytest-pythonpath
    - pytest-mock
    - graphviz
    - psutil
    - cryptography
    - pillow
    - discord.py
    - parse
    - dependencies/tesserocr-2.5.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
    - typing_extensions
    - colorama
    - dataclasses-json
```

I've installed the latest version of Miniconda and Git, both of which are the Dependencies.

Comment: doesn't sound like a `git` problem.

Comment: Are you cloning the git repository into the `envs/` directory? Generally, one should not ever need to manually manipulate stuff under the `miniconda3/` directory, including messing with environments. Instead, clone to a user-space, then follow the directions to create the environment.

Answer (score 1):

You have an existing Conda environment called botty. Delete that environment first.

Enter: `conda info --envs` or  `conda env list` to see a list of existing environment. if you see an environment *'botty'* listed, to remove this environment enter: `conda remove -n botty --all`.

If you still can't install manually delete the directory *C:\Users\super\miniconda3\envs\botty*

Then run your script